# show service tooltip on screen while using local administrator account to login

Tags: windows, service, autoit

this time I'm stuck with my AutoIt program. It works quite well not running as a service, but as a service there are some problems, and I wonder if I can fix em.

To my program: It uses the Tooltip-function of AutoIt to show current temperature on screen. It requieres read / write permissions.

About the service:
The service is created by using [svrany.exe](http://www.liutilities.com/products/wintaskspro/processlibrary/srvany/) as Host. It connects as a local administrator, so it has full write / read permissions as needed.

The only problem is: It cannot show any tooltip, but write it to a file. Is there any way to let the user at least decide if he wants to see that message? Like Windows asks, if you want to see what it shows, while using "local system"-account.

Comment: You are trying to run a script as a service which shows something on a screen when there is somebody logged on to the system, right? There are many ways to achieve that.

Comment: Yep you got it. That is exactly what I am trying to do.

Comment: I don't know whether it is possible to have a GUI interaction with a normal windows service although there is an option for that. I would create an Autoitscript executable and put that into the Startup folder of the user (with admin credentials if neccessary).

Comment: That would be a solution but I am searching for a very good solution that doesn't need another process.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look here. I guess there is no way without interacting with another process through the service.

https://www.autoitscript.com/forum/topic/80201-_service_udf-v4-build-your-own-service-with-autoit-code/